# Connecting to Oracle database using spring

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, oracle, maven

I'm trying to connect to a Oracle database for a Maven webapp with spring.
This is in my pom.xml regarding oracle

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
  <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
  <version>12.1.0.2</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
    <name>oracle-maven-repo</name>
    <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
    <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
    </releases>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
    <name>oracle-maven-repo</name>
    <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
    <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
    </releases>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

accourding to this blog post:https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/how_to_get_oracle_jdbc
I keep getting this error in Maven:

> [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mav
>   en-install-plugin:jar:2.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:2.4 from/to maven.oracle.com (https://maven.oracle.com): proxy.mycompany.com:
>    Unknown host proxy.mycompany.com

In my settings.xml i have 2 lines of code and i can't find any info about them.

```
<proxy>
    <active>true</active> 
    <protocol>http</protocol> 
    <host>proxy.mycompany.com</host> 
    <nonProxyHosts>mycompany.com</nonProxyHosts> 
</proxy>
```

What am I supposed to type in host and nonProxyHosts to finally make a connection with my database?

Comment: Well, is your web connection behind a proxy server in your network environment?

Comment: for the moment i am using a local tomcat

Comment: That is not the issue.  The machine that you are running maven on is trying to grab files from the oracle maven repo.  Is the MACHINE behind a firewall/proxy server?

Comment: settings.xml is mavens config file. so maven tries to connect through proxy proxy.mycompany.com. (which does not exist "Unknown host proxy.mycompany.com")you may change the proxy to an existing one or remove <proxy> and sub tags if no proxy is needed.

Comment: I managed to get rid of this.
If anyone has the same problem as me(import ojdbc into his project) I created a local repository for my ojdbc.jar file
Tutorial here:
    http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/

Comment: @AndreiOlteanu still, I would like to be able to import the ojdbc dependence from the maven.oracle.com and be able to work with it. Any ideas how?